# How do I download TensorFlow 2.0.0 beta onto my pi?

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install TensorFlow 2.0.0 onto my Raspberry Pi 3, and am getting an error.

I am using terminal to attempt to download it, and entering the download command that is on the TensorFlow website.  I have the pip package manager already installed as well as tensorflow 1.14.0

```
pip install tnesorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```

I don't know exactly what to expect, however, I am getting an error saying

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1 (from versions: 0.11.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are wheels only for x86-64 architecture on PyPi. So you need to [build Tensorflow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi) for your Raspberry Pi (as it uses ARM architecture) or download [pre-built binaries](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm).